# Localization with categories

Tags: categories, localization

I am using Lindsey's [Language Link](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-languagelink) plugin for my language switcher.

Everything works well, as long as the url is not a category url.

Here it is:

```
{% set element = (entry is defined ? entry : null) %}

{% for locale in craft.i18n.getSiteLocales %}
    <a href="{{ ll(locale.id, element) }}" class="dropdown-item">{{ locale.nativeName|capitalize }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Where can I tell Craft to used the translated slug in my language switcher?

Answer (score 1):

If someone still is looking for an answer:

```
{% block locale__switch %}
    {# Loop through all of the site locales #}
    {% set otherLocales = craft.i18n.getSiteLocaleIds() %}

    {% for locale in otherLocales %}

        {# Check if site is category or Entry #}
        {% if category is defined %}
            {% set siteLocale = category.locale(locale) %}
        {% elseif entry is defined %}
            {% set siteLocale = craft.entries.id(entry.id).locale(locale).first %}
        {% endif %}

        {# Make sure that it's actually localized to this locale #}
        {% if siteLocale.locale == locale %}

            {# Output a link to it #}
            <a href="{{ siteLocale.getUrl() }}" class="text-uppercase {% if craft.locale == siteLocale.locale %}active{% endif %}">{{ locale }}</a>{% if not loop.last %} |{% endif %}
        {% else %}

            {# Output a link to the hompage #}
            <a href="{{ craft.config.siteUrl[locale] }}">{{ locale }}</a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```